# Class/id/elements shortcut in non-HTML files

Tags: visual-studio-code

In HTML files, if I write for example:

```
span.my-first-span
```

and press enter, VS Code will automatically create a span with a class of my-first-span, like this:

```
<span class="my-first-span"></span>
```

how can I make it do the same on other files, such as .js, .jsx, etc?

I tried searching for it online, but I didn't find anything (I don't know if my search was the best, I don't really know how I should explain what I want...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following fields to your `settings.json` file in Visual Studio Code:

```json
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "javascript": "jsx"
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

The [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) plugin must be installed for it to work.

[image]

Comment: The Emmet plugin is automatically installed.  You don't have to install it yourself.

Comment: I just wanted to point it out in case this solution doesn't work.